# install Ubuntu hp laptop 15-d035dx

Tags: system-installation

I bought an hp 15-d035dx from Best Buy and asked if I would be able to install Linux on it and they said I should have no problem. I can't get the computer to boot to anything but windows. It won't boot to the cd or the usb. Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You must acess to your system's BIOS in order to change the boot sequence and boot from your install CD. To acess to your computer's BIOS setup, right after powering on the computer, quickly press F1 or F10 when the HP logo shows up, go to the Advanced Tab, then choose the Boot Order option with the arrow keys, finally, choose your CD/USB drive to boot first.
(More infos [here](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=fr&lc=fr&dlc=fr&docname=c00364979))
When Ubuntu will boot, carefully follow the steps when installing and enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in windows OS, plug in usb, sd card, or cd device that has ubuntu burned onto it. Then restart machine and press esc key at boot start, then a few option should come up and press f9 for boot option, then a window will come up to select what device you want to boot, here select usb, sd, or cd and now the machine should boot into ubuntu if it was properly burned onto device.